# Why not mapper/reducer for hadoop TeraSort

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, mapper

I am planning to insert some code into the mapper of the TeraSort class in Hadoop 0.20.2. However, after reviewing the source code, I cannot locate the segment that mapper is implemented.
Normally, we will see a method called job.setMapperClass() which indicates the mapper class. However, for the TeraSort, I can only see thing like setInputformat, setOutputFormat. I canno t find where the mapper and reduce methods are called?
can any one please give some hints about this? Thanks,
The source code is something like this,

```
public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
   LOG.info("starting");
   JobConf job = (JobConf) getConf();
   Path inputDir = new Path(args[0]);
   inputDir = inputDir.makeQualified(inputDir.getFileSystem(job));
   Path partitionFile = new Path(inputDir, TeraInputFormat.PARTITION_FILENAME);
   URI partitionUri = new URI(partitionFile.toString() +
                           "#" + TeraInputFormat.PARTITION_FILENAME);
   TeraInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, new Path(args[0]));
   FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
   job.setJobName("TeraSort");
   job.setJarByClass(TeraSort.class);
   job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
   job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
   job.setInputFormat(TeraInputFormat.class);
   job.setOutputFormat(TeraOutputFormat.class);
   job.setPartitionerClass(TotalOrderPartitioner.class);
   TeraInputFormat.writePartitionFile(job, partitionFile);
   DistributedCache.addCacheFile(partitionUri, job);
   DistributedCache.createSymlink(job);
   job.setInt("dfs.replication", 1);
   // TeraOutputFormat.setFinalSync(job, true);                                                                                                                                                                                             
   job.setNumReduceTasks(0);
   JobClient.runJob(job);
   LOG.info("done");
   return 0;
 }
```

For other classes, like TeraValidate, we can find the code like,

```
job.setMapperClass(ValidateMapper.class);
job.setReducerClass(ValidateReducer.class);
```

I cannot see such methods for TeraSort.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

Why should a sort need to set the `Mapper` and `Reducer` class for it?

The default value is the standard `Mapper` (former identity Mapper) and standard `Reducer`. 
These are the classes you usually inherit from.

You can basically say, that you're just emitting everything from the input and let Hadoop do its own sorting stuff. So sorting is working by "default".

Answer (score 1):

Thomas answer is right i.e mapper and reducers are identity since shuffled data is sorted before applying your reduce function . Whats special about terasort is its custom partitioner (which is not default hash function). You should read more about it from here [Hadoop's implementation for Terasort](http://sortbenchmark.org/YahooHadoop.pdf%3a). It states

"TeraSort is a standard map/reduce sort, except for a custom partitioner that uses a sorted list of N − 1 sampled keys that define the key range for each reduce. In particular, all keys such that sample[i − 1] <= key < sample[i] are sent to reduce i. This guarantees that the output of reduce i are all less than the output of reduce i+1."